# Mapbox GL JS, change POIs size

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js, mapbox-gl

I'd like to know if there is a way to change POIs size (schools, restaurants, ...)
[image].

I'm using Mapbox GL v2.8.2

On the documentation I only found about layers, but I'm not sure the "native" POIs are related to layers.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The POIs come from the Streets style. You can create a custom style in Mapbox Studio to edit the size of the POIs.

- Go to [studio.mapbox.com](https://studio.mapbox.com)
- Click Styles > New style
- Select Streets then click Customize Streets
- Under components, select Point of interest labels and adjust the Icon scale
- Click Publish
- Locate your new style in the list then click the 3 dots
- Copy the Style URL
- Set the `style` property of your map in Mapbox GL JS to your url

Comment: Great, I did'nt konw about it.
Thanks